# Break mode and Immediate Window results are different

Tags: ms-access

I am using MS Access 2016, Windows 10, USAF Laptop running SDC.

I am having an issue with debugging some code. When I hit a line in Break mode I get a Run-time Error '13':Type Mismatch, When I run the exact same code outside of break mode, the code functions properly.

Here is the basic code that is causing me problems:

```
Private Sub btn_ReqKey_Click() 'This is not all of the code only those lines that are necessary
Dim trgt_CACID as String
Dim Temp_KeyCode as String

trgt_CACID = Me.CACID.Value  'Pulls value from short text field of "1234567890"
'Here is the issue
Temp_KeyCode = UnlockCode(trgt_CACID) 'Run-time Error '13': Type mismacth
More code
End Sub

Public Function UnlockCode(ByVal CACID as String) As String
lots of code that generates a 25 digit Alpha code
End Function
```

When I click on the button the code fails at "Temp_KeyCode = UnlockCode(trgt_CACID)" Run-tine Error '13': type mismatch.

However, if I reset the code execution and run this in the immediate window without pressing the button.

```
trgt_CACID = "1234567890"
?UnlockCode(trgt_CACID)
```

Returns the proper code without throwing an error. So the function UnlockCode() works properly, just not at execution.

Additionally, When in break mode from pressing the button and I attempt the same line of code in the immediate window, it returns the same run-time error '13': Type mismatch.

Furthermore, I exit Break mode, reload the variable and execute the same line of code it works again.

So I know something in the execution environment is being affected, I cannot figure out what that is. This is the first time I have seen a disparity with how the immediate window functions as compare to code execution.

Side Note/Quirk, in the immediate when I enter the function, the helper pops up to guide me for the variables required. When I type the same in the module code, the helper pop ups do not display. So weird. Right? Further evidence something is different between the two environments.

Any help or assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
KO

Comment: The error is a Type Mismatch that does work when not in break mode. So the function is not the issue, besides its a substitution cypher, that breaks apart various data elements and reassigns them to Alpha Characters. I do not want to publish that code, so no I won't be providing that, and its not relative to the question at hand.

Comment: If have seen custom functions called from immediate window not work. Has something to do with how argument variables are declared. At least show the declaration line from your UnlockCode function. I have also had some procedures not work properly when a breakcode is set, or was it the opposite - haven't encountered in so long I forget.

Comment: I did, Public Function UnlockCode(ByVal CACID as String) As String. I use not other assignments that reference the CACID. I have 10 string assignments for each digit of the CACID. But all the types of data match as Strings.

Comment: So why does it work then in the Immediate window when I manually assigned the string value and the call the function using that value?

Comment: Okay, I looked at your prior post and removed the breakpoints, Still failed on execution same error. And right now still in break mode the function in the immediate window still returns the error. The variable trgt_CACID = "1234567890" in Watch Window.  I exit break mode reset all variables and manually reassign the trgt_CACID variable to "1234567890" the function works fine. It properly returns the code generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running it with a dummy function:

```vb
Public Function UnlockCode(ByVal CACID As Variant) As String
    UnlockCode = String(25, "0")
End Function
```

If that runs, debug your secret function.

Comment: However, when I call the function from the Immediate window outside of execution it returns 25 Zeros.

Comment: That - can you see - is not possible (if CACID is passed a string), so something else is going on - like a string is not passed to CACID. Try dimming as Variant (See editied code, please).

Comment: I realize its not supposed to work that way but it does. I have watches set to all the variable I am looking at, they are all strings. I even use ?trgt_CACID in the immediate window to prove it is a string and validate it value. Everything checks out, but stiull returns the error.

Comment: Sounds like you've got a duplicate declaration. UnlockCode might also be an object (in which case `UnlockCode(1)` calls the default method), an array (in which case `UnlockCode(1)` returns the item at index 1), a method of the object you're in (in which case that method is called), a property of the object you're in that's either an object or an array, etc .

Comment: Okay what DIM statement do you want set to Variant? the Calling Sub or the Function?

Comment: Nope no duplicate conflicting assignments anywhere. There is only the Function using that precise name.

Comment: Okay the Field name is also UnlockCode. I'll try changing that.

Comment: Well, there you are, all fields are added as properties of the form object by default, and fields are objects, so you're calling its default method or using its default property. Some people use [hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) to avoid errors like this (prepending all fields with `fld`, all functions with `fn`, etc) since they're notoriously hard to debug.

Comment: Nope not the Issue. Changed the field name on the form from UnlockCode to txt_UnlockCode still returns the Type Mismatch error. Crazy thing is your dummy code returns the same error right now in break mode. just killed break mode and it rtuns just fine. I even went so far as to add CStr(trgt_CACID) to force it to be a string and guess what? It still returns the same error. That is why I am at my wit's end.

Comment: Well, if a field called `UnlockCode` is in the record source the property stays, and you can't really prevent that. All fields in the record source are also added as a property.

Comment: The property on that field is Short Text so a string by default, but I'll change that too. Okay got a different error this time. Error 2465 cannot find the field 'UnlockCode". Okay based on this I decided to change the Function name to Code2Unock. That worked now.

Comment: Or, you could just use the full function path, e.g. `Module1.Function1`, which reduces ambiguity (as long as there's no second field that has a name equal to the module name you should be fine)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the discussions with Erik A and Gustav, I changed the Function name that was having a conflict with a table field name I was using. Once I changed everything to be dissimilar: table Field Name, Form Textbox name, and Function being called. Everything worked fine. So apparently the context I was calling from already had something using the name of the function and that field name was being picked up and sent to a function with the same name as the field. This created a subtle conflict that explains the disparity between execution in the context of table and form and when being Manually called in the Immediate Window AND why it worked in the Immediate window, but not during execution. Thank you Erik A and Gustav for their assistance.